# How not to be in "detached head" state, after CMake FetchContent through Git?

Tags: cmake

I use CMake's FetchContent_Declare and FetchContent_Populate to download dependencies from a Git repository. It looks like this:

```
FetchContent_Declare(my_subproject
    GIT_REPOSITORY http://127.0.0.1/my_subproject.git
    GIT_TAG master
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(my_subproject)
if(NOT my_subproject_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate( my_subproject )
endif()

target_link_libraries ( ${EXE_TARGET} my_subproject )
```

The download/clone looks fine, but *my_subproject* is in detached head state: it is pointing to "origin/master", instead of pointing to the local "master" branch.

Any tip on how to make "FetchContent_Populate" point to the local "master" branch?

I'm using CMake 3.21.1. This "issue" does not happen with CMake 3.17.2.

Comment: If this behavior depends only on the CMake version, not on the Git version, it's not a Git issue and doesn't need [tag:git]. Use [tag:git] if you want a workaround that *doesn't* use CMake itself, but since you seem to want this to all happen within CMake only, don't use the git tag.

Answer (score 0):

I only found this alternative solution :

```
execute_process(COMMAND git checkout ${_GIT_TAG} WORKING_DIRECTORY ${_SOURCE_DIR})
```

If you do this right after the `FetchContent_Populate()` or `FetchContent_MakeAvailable()` you will not be in `detached HEAD`.

But keep in mind that Fetching a branch is deprecated by CMake.
You should fetch from a git-tag or a commit SHA1.

If anyone has a better solution, I'm interested.